# multithreading on a tree

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Using boost I need to go to a tree for sequence alignment, start at the leaves and go through it by to leaves.  I have to make it multithreaded.  How can I achieve this, again using boost threads?

I want to go through the tree and check if its a leaf.  If so, align it and then wait for the others to be aligned, and then move to the next entry point.  Something like this:

```
              R
            /   \
           /     \
          {a}    {b}
         /  \    /  \
       {c}  {d} {e} [f]
       /    /
     [h]  [j]
```

where `f` is a leaf; so are `h` and `j`.  It needs to wait until there are no more leaves left before it moves into the next level, and so on.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I smell homework here...

Comment: I've tried to edit your question to make more sense of what "R---{a, b}---{c,d}{e,[f]}---{[h]}{[j]}" means. I think you've missed a leaf node in your question. Also, try to break your question into a more sentences than having them all in one.

Comment: thanks I try to do that, but that is cool, anyway the missing doesn't matter there could be any shape and any hundreds of nodes.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The question you've asked doesn't really fit the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for StackOverflow.  It is much too broad to treat here.  [Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134609/142865).  Please consult books and online guides to learn the basics.  If you have specific programming questions, we're happy to help with that.  There is a decent tutorial on Boost.Threads at the [Boost.Thread Website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using boost thread group and a deque, look it